# Splash screen while loading a url in a webview in android app

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, screen, splash-screen

I've got an app, that has 2 activity, the first one launch the second to load a url into a webview.

It works, but while the url is loading , the webview appear empty... then i want to make a splash screen or something like this, to show it while the url is loading, I did that in a new activity, but i don't know what can i do to close the third activity when the url is loaded... Please can anybody help me?

This is my code...Thank you!

```
public class Visor extends  Activity {

    WebView mWebView;
    int Result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.visor);
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String s= extras.getString("url");

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl(s);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new VisorClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        }

    private class VisorClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                lanzarIntro();
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
     }

    public void lanzarIntro(){
        Intent i=new Intent (this, Intro.class);

        startActivity(i);


    }



}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I do it by initially showing an ImageView and then once the WebView has loaded, swapping their visibility like this

```
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            ...

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.webView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


        });     
        wv.loadUrl("http://yoururlhere.com");
```

And my xml layout looks like this

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/vert_loading"
        />
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
```

Comment: If it is flickering, you might try to show the webview and then hide the loading image, instead of how I have it above.

Comment: For this to work, I had to wrap both within a `<FrameLayout>`. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get this to work. The ImageView never goes away. Logcat says `W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1970`

Answer (score 15):

I have one activity. 1 xml file and 1 java class. Inside xml file i have:

1. WebView
2. ImageView, logo of my application,
3. ProgressBar and
4. TextView, app version .

Code of main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"
    a:layout_height="fill_parent"
    a:background="#aaaaaa"
    a:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    a:id="@+id/webView1"
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"
    a:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ImageView
    a:id="@+id/imageView1"
    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    a:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    a:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    a:src="@drawable/logo" />

<ProgressBar
    a:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    a:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    a:id="@+id/textView1"
    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    a:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    a:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
    a:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    a:text="version 1.0"
    a:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    a:textColor="#444444" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code of NovcanikActivity.java:

```
package zm.Nocanik;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NovcanikActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();

    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    websettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    websettings.setSavePassword(false);

    webview.loadUrl("http://m.novcanik.net/?appvers=1.0");
    webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.setBackgroundColor(128);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new NovcanikWebViewClient());

    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });




}

public void visible(){

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    TextView version = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    webview.setVisibility(10);

    logo.setVisibility(0);

    bar.setVisibility(0);

    version.setVisibility(0);

}

public void unvisible(){

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    TextView version = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    webview.setVisibility(0);

    logo.setVisibility(10);

    bar.setVisibility(10);

    version.setVisibility(10);

}


private class NovcanikWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url){
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
        String description, String failingUrl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/noconnection.html");
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

    visible();

}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    unvisible();

}

}

}
```

Sorry for no description. If there would be need for description, i will describe in detail the entire code.

Comment: This is exactly. what i want. Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing

Comment: What is webview.setVisibility(10), webview.setVisibility(0) & webview.setBackgroundColor(128) ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use         `mWebView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));` for your mWebView