# Errors implementing splash screen for webview

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I'm trying to implement a splash screen for my webview android app, so that it will display until the page is fully loaded. I was using the code from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589365/splash-screen-while-loading-a-url-in-a-webview-in-android-app) but am running into some errors that I'm not sure how to solve. I assume that I'm missing a library of some sort, but I have no idea what.

The errors I'm getting are:

> View cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value @drawable/vert_loading')

The code where I'm getting the view errors is:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

While my layout xml file is:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/vert_loading"
/>
```

My assumption is that I might be missing an import of some sort, but I wouldn't know which one. The ones I have are:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is your vert_loading image ?

Comment: you have `vert_loading` image in drawable folder

Comment: For future reference, it couldn't have been a problem with an import. That would have resulted in a compiler error; import statements don't have any effect on code, they are merely syntactic sugar that lets you type `... extends Activity` instead of `... extends android.app.Activity`, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an **drawable** folder in your project **res** from *File->New->Folder*  and put your drawable `vert_loading` in res->drawable  folder. then Clean your project from **Project->Clean**.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I had it in a root drawable folder instead of in res/drawable. This is my first android app so still making stupid mistakes.