# Animated loading webview android

Tags: php, android, html, animation, webview

i've got a webview app,
i want an animated loading bar.

i found this on stackoverflow 
[Splash screen while loading a url in a webview in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589365/splash-screen-while-loading-a-url-in-a-webview-in-android-app)

but it isn't what i really need, i've made a .gif image that display my logo and a loading bar, animated obviusly, but when i put it in an imageview it isn't animated..

and i want also to set another loading bar with opacity for all page of my webview, is it possible?

Comment: I highly recommend editing your question to use proper capitalization; people will be discouraged to answer if you can't even be bothered to capitalize things correctly.

Comment: capitalization isn't a problem. but the utter lack of any useful code examples is the kicker. we can't help fix what we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Start animation in OnCreate. Just implement WebViewClient and extend onPageFinished() as follows:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // stop animation here 
    }
});
```