# Unable to get ImageView by id

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to show a splash screen until the app finishes loading the URL.
After searching, I found a solution - [Splash screen while loading a url in a webview in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589365/splash-screen-while-loading-a-url-in-a-webview-in-android-app)

But I'm unable to implement it on my current code. I'm getting an error message while trying to get the splash image view by id.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private final Context context;

    public MyAppWebViewClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.contains("?dl=1")) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            // Make a new request pointing to the download url
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }

            String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
            String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, fileExtension);

            // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
            return true;
        }



        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.example.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/offline.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //hide loading image
        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_logo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //show webview
        view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

and activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_splash_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/splash_logo"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem occuring in this line :

```
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_logo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.myapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(MainActivity.this));

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        // Request required permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        // Add user agent suffix
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
                this.mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString()
                        + " "
                        + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
                        + "/"
                        + BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
        );
    }

    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The post that you linked to has code within an `Activity`, where you can call `findViewById`. Your code here is within a `WebViewClient`, so you can't call `findViewById` since that is not a method of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `onPageFinished` within the Activity class if you want to use `findViewById`.

Also, if you don't need a reference to the splash image, then don't keep one.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(MainActivity.this) {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //hide loading image
        findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_logo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //show webview
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");
```

Comment: this code is running but the splash screen not working as it should..... as linked question

Comment: I don't have your device, so I don't know what you are looking at, but if this solved your problem of the code not running, then I suggest you accept this answer and make a new post to describing what you mean by "as it should."

Answer (score 1):

Your encompassing class is not a `Activity`. There is no `findViewbyId()` in `WebViewClient` class.

Comment: instead of making MyAppWebViewClient as a public class, make this a inner class of MainActivity. Then you will get the findViewById() there without any further issues. Btw, you need to also care for @Bob Malooga'r case after that.

Answer (score 0):

Split this line

```
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_logo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

into two separate statements

```
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_logo);
myImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Error:(78, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable myImageView
Error:(78, 35) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use findViewById with any view context. As you don't have any View reference.

You must init or call findViewById, wherever you are calling or initiating below code.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

> Initiate this also

```
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_logo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ImageView myImageView = 
        (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_logo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```